# All the errors are coming when I am trying to call this customized macro

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, macros, compiler-errors

## define ERROR_CHECK_SERVER(x)\

```
({\
if (globalError) 
{\
    MM_MSG_PRIO(MM_GENERAL, MM_PRIO_ERROR, x);\
    stop = true;\
    break;\
}\
})
```

code @ line no.

131         status = acceptConnect(caddr);

132          ERROR_CHECK_SERVER("RTSP_LIB :: acceptConnect failed");

Here is the error list

Error   4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'      132
Error   5   error C2059: syntax error : ')'                 132
Error   6   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'      132
Error   8   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'      216
Error   9   error C2059: syntax error : ')'                 216
Error   10  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'      216
Error   12  error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'      236
Error   13  error C2059: syntax error : ')'                 236
Error   14  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'      236

Answer (score 1):

First, you missed the "\" at the end of 2nd line.

Second, why you enclosed all your macro body into ()? This may make the compiler angry.